# Windows 7 Meteor UP (MUP) Error: spawn ENOENT

Tags: windows-7, ssh, meteor, meteor-up

I am new to meteorjs. I created an app that I am uploading to server using Meteor UP (MUP). I have dedicated linux server with cPanel installed. I can access the server through SSH.

I have windows 7 on my local setup from where I am trying to deploy the app. I created a private key and am using it with MUP to deploy the app. But when I run `mup setup` in command prompt, it gives me the following error:

```
Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------


Started TaskList: Setup
[207.244.66.193] - Installing Node.js
[207.244.66.193] ? Installing Node.js: FAILED
        spawn ENOENT
Completed TaskList: Setup
```

Here is my mup.json file

```
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
      "username": "devmain",
      //"password": "password"
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      "pem": "/Users/Jackal/Desktop/mup1"
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  "setupMongo": true,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.25 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.25",

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": true,

  // Application name (No spaces)
  "appName": "myappname",

  // Location of app (local directory)
  "app": "/Users/Jackal/Desktop/app",

  // Configure environment
  "env": {
    "PORT": 3000,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://myapp.com"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
  // before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

Can someone please identify what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: are you running a debian or ubuntu system? cause it needs the apt package manager to be present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running cPanel, its highly likely that you are not running a debian based operating system, since it only support redhat based systems, since MeteorUP relies on the `apt` command, and thats only available on debian based systems, MeteorUP will **not** work.

To run your app in production you can use systemd:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=[path_to_your_meteor_cmd] [path_to_your_app]
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=[your_app_name]
User=[user_it_runs_under]
Group=[group_it_runs_under]
Environment=NODE_ENV=production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

save it as `[your_app_name].service` and after you replaced every `[]` with correct values, place the script in `/etc/systemd/system/`, then run the commands `systemctl enable [appname].service` and `systemctl start [appname].service`, the enable will start your app automatically after a reboot/crash.

Here is mine for reference:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/meteor /home/meteor-run/spottr/
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=spottr
User=spottr
Group=spottr
Environment=NODE_ENV=production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I checked and it was running redhat system :(

Comment: Couldnt leave you hanging like that, so i gave a alternative that you can do it yourself with systemd :-)